# Problems making the swift compiler to work

Tags: raspbian-jessie, software-installation, software-compatibility, swift

I have installed the swift 3.0 compiler on my raspberry pi 3 (raspbian jessie), but I am getting the following errors while trying to run the interpreter or the compiler.

```
swift: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by swift)
swift: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by swift)
```

Any ideas how to make this happen?

Comment: Might be useful to indicate where the swift compiler came from.

Comment: @goldilocks: I fetched it from here http://swift-arm.ddns.net/job/Swift-3.0-Pi3-ARM-Incremental/16/artifact/swift-3.0-2016-07-19-RPi23-ubuntu16.04.tar.gz

Now I saw it is for ubuntu :( 

Should I close the question and ask instead how to get swift working on raspbian?

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: You can ask but I think you are out of luck; you are best off switching to ubuntu if you want that.   If you do ask use this page link: http://swift-arm.ddns.net/job/Swift-3.0-Pi3-ARM-Incremental/16/ -- not something that downloads a compressed archive ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing libstdc++ and g++, then run ldconfig.

```
$sudo apt-get install libstdc++6 build-essential 
$sudo ldconfig
```

I've never used or installed swift, my answer is based on the error message provided.
if you have g++, and libstdc++ installed, then prehaps try placing a link to the location of those files in the place where swift is looking for them.

I would use the locate command, but I also realize some Raspi distros omit the locate command (madness), if you dont have it, install that too.

$sudo locate libstdc++

I would expect it to be in /usr/lib/gcc  some place. 
once you locate the librarys you need, check the paths against what swift expects. if swift is looking in the wrong place, make a symlink to the correct location with `ln -s`.

Comment: *"my answer is based on the error message provided"* -> I think if you look at that error it's not because it isn't installed.